# Magento: Custom field for specific product type

Tags: php, magento, field, e-commerce, product

I have to add a text field for every product of specific attribute set.

Please see this link:
http://www.budgetdiamondsonline.com/crown-vintage-style-engagement-ring-14k-white-gold

Here there is a check box Engrave. I want to add like this field.

NEED HELP.

Comment: You can create a product attribute for the same. Could be custom options as well

Comment: Yes I can but I need to interact with user by a text box. User will enter a text and admin can see that from admin panel.

Comment: Interact user with text box is allowing user to enter input values and saving it with your product as an attribute or custom option

Comment: I could not make it as attribute. I tried custom option, but its for individual product. I need to do same thing for all product, so its not possible to add custom option by admin, because its time consuming. Please comment if you have any idea.

Comment: Why you cant make it as an attribute ? That will be associated with each or any product you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Product attribute values in Magento are specified by admin and not interact with users.

To add a checkbox (or field of other type) to product that user can select - you should create a custom option.

1. Log in to Admin
2. Go to Catalog -> Manage Products
3. Click on the row with your product
4. Go to Custom Options tab
5. Click "Add New Option" button
6. Specify the title in "Title" field (title for section of checkboxes)
7. Select "Checkbox" in Input type dropdown
8. Click "Add New Row" button
9. Type  name of checkbox to row's "Title" field
10. Save the product
11. Clear cache and check result on frontend

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This solution is for a single product. But I want to do this automatic when admin just add a product.

Comment: Hi @FerojBepari I'm wondering if you found a solution to your problem? I have the same issue :S